# PHP: MySQL Select with multiple Where

Tags: php, mysql

I looked mostly everywhere on Stackoverflow for adding multiple WHERE instances but none of them seem to work.

My Select query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE user = $user AND column = 1");          //query
```

I tried IN and some other ways but I dont know why it wont get the column. If I take out the user column it works, but I want it to also restrict to the column as well..

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE user = '$user' AND column = 1"); - this should work but I don't recommend you to use it. it's not a safe option. take a look at prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: **AND** is what you need.

Comment: what is the value of `$tableName` and `$user`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`column` is reserved word in `mysql`. You have to use `` ` `` around that kind of column_name and use `'` single quotes around string data `'$user'`

```
SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE user = '$user' AND `column` = 1
```

Comment: Yea, here comes the right answer, also you might like to add single quotes around user? LOL you did it already, +1

Comment: Thanks! :) I did for both table fields so `user` = '$user' AND `column` = '1'. And it works, thanks for the tip and explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the username in single-quotes & as mentioned by Yogesh column is a reserved keyword in MySQL. Try this:

```
user = '$user' AND `column` = 1
```

So the whole statement becomes:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE user = '$user' AND `column` = 1");
```

Also, you should be using mysqli or PDO with prepared statements instead.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your query. Use the below code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `".$tableName."` WHERE user = '".$user."' AND `column` = 1");
```

And here I am missing that what is column in query is it name of column?
And you need to give the value in single quota and table name in ` till mark.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE user = "'.$user.'" AND `column` = 1';
```